# Как по оптоволоконному проводу происходит одновременно передача "туда-сюда"?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Всем привет. Мне стало интересно как по оптоволоконному кабелю происходит передача данных? А точнее как по ОДНОМУ шнуру происходит передача в ОБА направления (и происходит ли вообще?), как на приём, так и на ответ?

Comment: так же как и по любому другому кабелю) одновременно только в одну сторону. А подробности зависят от устройства сети.

Comment: pavel, тоесть нужно чтобы было два кабеля, один на приём, другой на ответ ?

Comment: это полный дуплекс будет, но можно просто по очереди передавать. Вам обычно нет необходимости передавать в 2 стороны одновременно.

Comment: теоретически, кроме иных способов, можно кодировать информацию на разных частотах. но конкретно в этом случае вряд ли применяется такой способ.

Comment: Ну а в обычных домашних условиях короче как я понял достаточно и одного, который заходит с подъезда в маршрутизатор.

Comment: @pavel, Могу ошибаться, но кажется, можно одновременно по оптике слать сигнал сразу с двух сторон. Вроде просто луч под разными углами пускается

Comment: @koks_rs можно, точнее я бы сказал что угол один, просто начальный отступ разный (со смещением идут).

Comment: Всё, спасибо всем, разобрался :D

Comment: Внутри одного шнура два помельче

Comment: @koks_rs Чтобы по одному проводу гонять туда-сюда нужен же совмещённый приёмо-передатчик, верно я понимаю? Давно ли совмещают диод (или что там сейчас) для излучения света и фотодиод для его приёма?